# How to concat item to the last array inside the root array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, data-structures, ecmascript-6

Basically, when I press a button, my function will start to listen for coordinates changes and concat newly collected data into the array.

When the button is pressed again, the listener will be removed. The user can press the button and start listening to a new set of coordinates again. They can do this repeatedly.

```
this.state = {
    pathArray: [], // originally a 1D array, should become 2D as user keep using the app
    pathCount: 0,
}
```

This is how the final array should look like so that I can proceed with the rendering part. I want to be able to dynamically create a new index in the array so that new data will be pushed into the bottom of the list.

How can I create a new array inside the root array when the button is pressed, and keep appending objects into the child array until the button is pressed again. If the button is pressed again the new child array would be created again, and the process goes on and on.

```
pathArray = [
    [ 
        { lat: 0, long: 0 },
        { lat: 1, long: 2 },
    ],
    [ 
        { lat: 0, long: 0 },
        { lat: 1, long: 2 },
    ],
]
```

```js
onButtonPressed = () => {
    const { running } = this.state
    if (!this.state.running) {
      this.followWatchCoords() // start collecting data
    } else {
      this.stopFollowing() //stop collecting data
    }
  }
```

```js
followWatchCoords = () => {
    this.followUserWatchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(({ coords }) => {
    
      this.calculateDistance(coords)

    }, null, GEOLOCATION_SETTINGS)
  }
```

```js
calculateDistance = (coords) => {
    const { latitude, longitude } = coords

    const positionLatLong = pick(coords, ['latitude', 'longitude'])

    let newArr = this.state.pathArray.slice(); //copy array to mutate
    newArr.push(positionLatLong)


    this.setState({
      pathArray: newArr,
    })
  }
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: How can I create a new array inside the root array when the button is pressed, and keep appending objects into the child array until the button is pressed again. If the button is pressed again the new child array would be created again, and the process goes on and on.

Comment: This button does it trigger a repeating process where an entry is done every X seconds until the button is pressed again?

Comment: basically, the button triggers another function (a GPS listener) and this is where I manipulate the arrays. Yes you got it @Chris

Comment: To create new array at the end of the list: `pathArray.push([])`. To append elements in this newly created array: `pathArray[pathArray.length - 1].push({lat: 1, long: 2})`.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia reactjs does not let me to do pathArray[pathArray] in the setState block...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally sorted out after some useful advice given by Chris

In my button function, I create a new child array every time its called

```
this.setState({
    routeCoordinates: this.state.routeCoordinates.concat([[]]), //add array
    routeCount: this.state.routeCount + 1
})
```

also increase routeCount by one every time the button is pressed (initially -1 due to the nature of array)

Then in the GPS listener, because the calculateDistance function will be called every time new data comes in, we just need to do the following

```
let newArr = [...routeCoordinates]
newArr[routeCount].push(positionLatLong)

this.setState({ routeCoordinates: newArr })
```

The trick is to use concat and push wisely

Comment: Glad you figured out a solution. You should accept your own answer, and consider upvoting mine if you found it useful. Thanks.

Comment: Sure! Will accept my answer after 2 days (SO's constraint)

Answer (score 1):

Below a simple snippet of how you could implement this.

Basically, the order of events are:

1. Clicking the button triggers the `_startStop()` function which starts an interval.
2. The interval fetches the lat/long coordinates from a fake GPS API every 3000 ms.
3. The new coordinates are pushed into the state array.

If you click the button again, the same function is triggered, but the interval is cleared and the process stopped.

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.interval;
    this.state = {arr: []};
    this._getFakeCoords = this._getFakeCoords.bind(this);
    this._startStop = this._startStop.bind(this);
  }
  
  _getFakeCoords() {   
    return {lat: Math.random() * 100, long: Math.random() * 100};
  }
  
  _startStop() {
    if(this.interval) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      this.interval = null;
    } else {
      let newArr = this.state.arr.slice();  //copy the array so we can mutate it
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        newArr.push([this._getFakeCoords(), this._getFakeCoords()]);
        this.setState({arr: newArr});  //replace the old array with the mutated one
        console.log(newArr);  //preview the result
      }, 3000);
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <button onClick={this._startStop}>Start/Stop</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Seems doable but 2 things. First, the geolocation library releases new data every few milliseconds, so the setInterval function probably not gonna be useful here. The component that I used to render lines takes 1 array of objects to render 1 line. 2 objects = 1 line, multiple objects (in 1 array) = 1 really long line. So ideally, if my pathArray has 2 child arrays, then we should be expecting 2 lines.

Comment: Just tried your approach but it does not match my requirements haha, let me update my post with my current code

Comment: @J.Doe, okay, but this is just a proof of concept. Not a complete solution. If your API works differently, then just modify the code accordingly. I guess the question here then will be how to convert the array or whatever. Just update that part - i.e how the array looks like at first, and how the result should look like. I'll only update that part.

Comment: I have updated the post with my code, as you can see the calculateDistance function will be updated everytime the geolocation library collected new data.

Comment: @J.Doe, okay. I don't see the part with the 1D -> 2D array problem. *That's* the issue here, right?

Comment: Haha man, the calculateDistance will be executed perhaps thousands of times for every button session. The trick to this problem is new data will always be added to the bottom of the list. So perhaps we can create an empty array when the button first pressed, then append data into the last child of the array?? hmmm

Comment: @J.Doe you explain your problem poorly and you have a bunch of code that is irrelevant to the programming issue you're asking about. It makes it hard for others to follow because you are explaining your whole app rather than the specific problem... anyway, if I understand this correctly, you could perhaps use two arrays - one for the `pathArray` and another `tempArray`. `tempArray` starts populating with coords when you click the button to start, and when you stop, you push the `tempArray` into the `pathArray`?

Comment: I accept your criticism and will work on my delivery problem. My component should access the last childArray in real time. So if we push tempArray into the pathArray only after the button is pressed again, then it would be missing the point because my app needs to draw path in real time :(

Comment: the logic seems to be correct but when I push a new array it returns index of 1, then I tried to push data into the array it shows 'Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145471/discussion-between-chris-and-j-doe).